# Extra spacing in my list of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, koma-script

Latex puts an extra spacing between two entries in my list of tables.

The spacing happens before the first table that is actually found in the appendix.

The last table not found in the appendix is a longtable.

Code:

```
\begin{longtable} {l c | p{1.4cm}  p{1.4cm} p{1.4cm} p{1.4cm} }
\centering
Stuff & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff & Stuff \\
\caption{Stuffcaption}
\end{longtable}
```

The first entry in the appendix was put inside a minipage because otherwise it was not possible to use \caption and \captionof was not a suitable alternative.

Code:

```
\section{AppendixStuff}
\begin{minipage} {\linewidth}
\captionsetup{type=table}
\begin{tabularx} {\linewidth} { p{4cm} p{5cm} c}
\toprule 
\textbf{AppendixStuff} & \textbf{AppendixStuff} & \textbf{AppendixStuff}\\
\midrule
AppendixStuff & AppendixStuff & AppendixStuff \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{AppendixStuff}
\end{minipage}
```

There's one extra empty line in my list of tables. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Why is \captionof not suitable?  The version from the capt-of packages doesn't have the same side effects as the one from caption.  Alernativley, just use `\makeatletter\def\@captype{table}\makeatother` inside the minipage.

Comment: @JohnKormylo \captionof had unintended side effects with table numbering. Do you suppose the minipages are related to the problem at hand?

Comment: In general when you ask questions here your MWE should be a complete minimal working example meaning a complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Aside: it's simply wrong to use a `tabularx` environment without at least one column of type `X`.

Comment: RE table numbering.  Try putting a \clearpage in front of \appendix or \section.  Also, check \thetable before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the vertical space between tables of different chapters like here:

[image: list of tables with chapter gap]

KOMA-Script class `scrbook` and `scrreprt` provide option `listof=nochaptergap` to remove this *chapter gap*:

```
\documentclass[listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\chapter{First}
\captionof{table}{First table in first chapter}
\captionof{table}{Second table in first chapter}
\chapter{Second}
\captionof{table}{First table in second chapter}
\captionof{table}{Second table in second chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{First}
\captionof{table}{First table in first appendix}
\captionof{table}{Second table in first appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image: list of tables without chapter gap]

You could even set this option for the appendix only:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{\KOMAoptions{listof=nochaptergap}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\chapter{First}
\captionof{table}{First table in first chapter}
\captionof{table}{Second table in first chapter}
\chapter{Second}
\captionof{table}{First table in second chapter}
\captionof{table}{Second table in second chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{First}
\captionof{table}{First table in first appendix}
\captionof{table}{Second table in first appendix}
\end{document}
```

but I would recommend to do so, because the result is ugly and inconsistent:

[image: list of tables without chapter gap for the appendix only]

KOMA-Script does also provide options to change the gap distance or add the chapter headings via option `chapteratlists` to the list of figures and list of tables (and other similar lists). See the [KOMA-Script manual](https://komascript.de/scrguien) or [German KOMA-Script manual](https://komascript.de/scrguide) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as answer)

Your posting contains quite a few assertions -- such as "Latex puts an extra spacing between two entries in my list of tables" and "The first entry in the appendix was put inside a `minipage` because otherwise it was not possible to use `\caption`" -- but provides *no basis* for replicating the issues you're facing.

The following MWE (minimum working example), which tries to build on the code snippets and other tidbits of information you've provided, does not replicate none of the issue you say you're encountering.

Please be (much!) more specific as to what you're actually doing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\bigskip\hrule

\section{A normal section}

\begin{longtable}{lll}
\caption{A longtable}\\
\toprule
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\appendix

\section{Appendix with a tabularx table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XXX @{}}
\toprule 
\textbf{Appendix Stuff} & \textbf{Appendix Stuff} &  \textbf{Appendix Stuff}\\
\midrule
Appendix Stuff & Appendix Stuff & Appendix Stuff \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Appendix Stuff, Take 1}
\end{table}


\section{Appendix with a tabular* table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lcr @{}}
\toprule 
\textbf{Appendix Stuff} & \textbf{Appendix Stuff} & \textbf{Appendix Stuff}\\
\midrule
Appendix Stuff & Appendix Stuff & Appendix Stuff \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Appendix Stuff, Take 2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. I really appreciate it. I will accept this as an answer because it confirms my suspicion that the problem is rooted elsewhere.